# How to add custom field to content view?

Tags: views

I would like to add to my main content view in drupal 7 (the one with the path /admin/content) a custom field called "mobile friendly".
This field should tell the user if the current node is mobile friendly. The values should be "yes" or "no".

The values theme selves are in special dedicated table which has 2 columns: the first is "nid" and the second is "mobile_friendly" (which is either "1" or "0")

I would like this field to be sortable and and i would like to filter by it also.

i have looked in the Drupal docs but didn't understood how to do it.

Can someone give me please an example in code or refer me to some close example?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

View module doesn't have access to the custom tables by default, but you can fix it using hook_views_data function. More information you may find here http://www.sitepoint.com/exposing-tables-views-drupal-7/